# ng-grid not displaying columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm new with AngularJS. Right now, I'm trying to get my ng-grid working in a directive.
I populated my table asynchronously (updating the data and columnDefs properties). It worked fine.
Now when I receive the data, I set a default grouping in code and what I get at launch is :
- The columns and data are not visible but the groups are.
- If I resize my window, the columns and data appear.

I guess it has something to do with refresh, but I couldn't find a way to trigger a refresh of the component on my own.

Maybe you can help :)

Comment: Hi, could you share some relevant code? Are you retrieving your data async with a solution like this ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120188/get-ajax-data-into-angular-grid How are you updating the columnDefs dynamically?

Comment: You got a point with the columnDefs ! I was overwriting the whole gridOption every time ! I put it in the scope, and I refer to the columnDefs with a string. It looks fine now !
Thank you.